# Add space in the string before certain characters

Tags: php, string

How to put white spaces before and after a character in text field?

eg. `Text="John123456"`

So, what I need is a white space before 456.

Comment: Go to the text field and `click space bar` after `John123`.

Comment: how it is related with css ?

Comment: Do you want to do it 3 characters before the end of the string every time?

Comment: Easy as: `echo preg_replace('/(\d{3})$/', ' $1', $str);`.

Comment: the last 3 char not always same it is change every time. so i put space before last 3 char

Comment: Thanks Amal Murali "preg_replace('/(\d{3})$/', ' $1'," has solved my problem.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for...

```
substr_replace($text, ' ' . substr($text, -3), -3);
```

This will replace the last 3 characters of a string with a space plus those three characters.

Comment: nice, can't say i've ever used `substr_replace`

Answer (score 5):

Do something like this

```
$str="John123456";
echo $str = str_replace("456"," 456",$str);
```

Comment: Why have they downvoted your answer is legit as for me

Comment: the $str is fetching from database and this is customers id and i try to add space before last three character

Comment: `$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($s)-3) . ' ' . substr($str, -3);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$str1 = "John";
$str2 = 123456;

for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
    $str = $str1 . $str2;

    $length = strlen($str);
    $lastChars = substr($str,$length-3,3);

    echo add_space($str, $lastChars);
    echo "<br/>";

    $str2++;
}
```

In this example, '$str1' can be username & '$str2' can be the auto-increment number. Using this you get the output like this

```
John123 456
John123 457
John123 458
John123 459
John123 460
John123 461
John123 462
John123 463
John123 464
John123 465
```

Comment: this id is auto generate in 10 character. So, the user is john and the id 'john123456' auto generated in 10 character. i have need space before last three char. The last 3 char not always 456 it can be changed @Radhika

Comment: This doesn't work if the OP doesn't know what the last three characters will be.